# reference for a Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability

I have encountered the following inequality in an article, which is termed as  Hoeffding's inequality; however, i cant find a reference for it. can someone give me a reference, or reason why its true

$$P(|\frac1n\sum a-E[a]|>=c)<=e^{nc^2/8}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

Comment: @Sisyphus yes I have seen that, but the one i have written is different